# How can I run go-ethereum as daemon process on Ubuntu?

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, daemon

The [Installation Instructions for Ubuntu](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) suggest running `geth` from the command line, how can I run it as daemon process / service on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Run as a systemd service

Create a file `geth.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ethereum go client

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=geth 2>%h/.ethereum/geth.log

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enable service:

```
systemctl --user enable geth.service
systemctl --user start geth.service
```

[Source](https://github.com/bas-vk/config/blob/master/geth-systemd-service.md).

#### Alternatively you could use screen:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install screen -y
```

Then you can make a bash similar to this (`~/geth.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting geth"
screen -dmS geth /usr/bin/geth --verbosity 3
```

now let's make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/geth.sh
```

You can now run the bash `~/geth.sh`

> You attach to the screen with screen -x geth
>
> You detach from the screen by pressing CTRL + a then d

If you want to attach to the geth console after the process runs in the background (or in screen), you can use:

```
geth attach
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3kpfrb/how_do_you_run_geth_in_background/cv0zwjs).

#### Or simply fork it in background:

When starting geht, put a `&` at the end of the command in a terminal:

```
geth --rpc &
```

Before closing the terminal you should disown the process:

```
disown
```

You could also pipe the logs to a file like that:

```
geth --verbosity 4 --rpc 2>> /path/to/logfile
```

But don't forget to disown it before you close the terminal.

[Source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#geth-javascript-runtime-environment).

Comment: Great answer. The "systemd" should probably be the first example though - at least it's what I would have expected to find as the top answer.

Comment: You have my vote, but agree that the systemd section is probably the most relevant portion of the answer.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Awesome, this is an excellent answer!

Comment: Systemd method: Failed to enable unit: File geth.service: No such file or directory. I'm saving the file in my home folder and I'm executing the command there.

Comment: @emisilva I had a similar problem, which I solved by changing:
1) changing the enable command to sudo & making the path an absolute path: `sudo systemctl --user enable /home/ubuntu/geth.service`
2) also had to change the command to an absolute path in the service: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/geth ...`

Comment: Why do we need to disown? @5chdn

Comment: Wouldn't you want to append to the log in the service file?  `2>>` instead of `2>`?

Comment: The `ExecStart` line does not work for me. According to the systemd documentation, "Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported." I also find, contra the systemd documentation, that an absolute path to the binary is needed.

Comment: How to run Geth using its flags in daemon mode with your solution?

Answer (score 16):

Just using this command is enough for me:

```
nohup geth --rpc &
```

To check if service is running:

```
ps ax | grep geth
```

To explore last log messages:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

To stop the service I use:

```
pkill geth
```

Comment: To get a console, geth attach

Comment: `killall geth` seems like a better option to stop the geth-process.

Comment: that's exactly what i need!

Comment: @alper `killall geth` doesn't work with `nohup`

Comment: @e18r try: `kill -9 $(pgrep -f -l geth | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: @alper actually `killall geth` does work. You just have to wait a few minutes for it to close gracefully

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update to 5chdn's answer that uses `systemd`. This shows how to run a headless `geth` on your Ubuntu server.

*Of course, you must install the command line tools first, see https://www.ethereum.org/cli. You should also run MyEtherWallet on your normal desktop computer to create an account + private key so you can receive funds.*

## Step 1: put on your cape

```
sudo bash
```

Other steps here are based on you running as root. If you are *not* running as root then learn about [using systemd with user processes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User). tl;dr in this case they would only run after you login, but you can configure so a user service starts as boot

## Step 2: make a service

```
cat > /root/geth.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Ethereum go client

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/geth --etherbase 0xe677698ab732Aa1E56CF2A7997a00e3FA6F5bD88 2>%h/.ethereum/geth.log

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF
```

Above, you can substitute your own wallet's etherbase. If you don't specify an etherbase then `geth` will emit a warning.

## Step 3: run it

```
systemctl --user enable /root/geth.service
systemctl --user start geth.service
```

This will run it now and after you reboot.

## Step 4: test it

```
sleep 5 # The geth server takes a few seconds to boot up
geth attach
```

If `geth attach` is successful, you will know the `geth` server is running, and you'll see:

> Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

If something messed up then you'll see:

> Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /root/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to run as systemd:

Create geth.service file (/etc/systemd/system/geth.service):

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/geth.service
```

Paste the below

```
[Unit]
Description=Geth

[Service]
Type=simple
User={$USER}
Restart=always
RestartSec=12
ExecStart=/bin/geth --syncmode "full" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Replace {$USER} with username above. Use [useradd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) to create a newUser if required.

```
sudo useradd -d /home/newUser -m --uid 10000 newUser
```

Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

service geth status
sudo service geth start
```

Check the status:

```
service geth status
```

Attaching to geth instance:

```
geth attach
```

Stop and disable the service:

```
sudo service geth stop
sudo systemctl disable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the accepted answer is great, it didn't work for me. Most likely because I am on AWS Linux AMI (eugh, I know). I intend on switching at some point (systemctl not  So far, this seems to have worked for me:

1. Create file /etc/init.d/geth-testnet

```
#!/bin/bash
#chkconfig: 2345 20 80
#description Start RPC testnet

su ec2-user -c '/path/to/geth --verbosity 3 --testnet --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"'
```

2. Run

```
chmod +x geth-testnet
chkconfig --add geth-testnet
chkconfig --level 345 geth-testnet on
```

Comment: I may be wrong but is this part of the above command: '--rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain="*" ' opening geth ports to possible attack? I seem to remember some posting five or six months ago about someone losing ether when running geth with ports open to the whole world as this is saying. Might be wrong though. I'm sure someone will correct me if I am.

Comment: for safety, maybe anyone who finds this remove that part until someone confirms or denies what @ThomasJayRush said