# Is there the start/stop script of geth after Debian/Ubuntu booting?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any start/stop shell script for geth which is executed after Debian or Ubuntu OS boot up?

For example, startup scripts usually located under

/etc/init.d/
/etc/rc.local

Comment: maybe duplicate: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-run-go-ethereum-as-daemon-process-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I won't get into a system.d vs sysvinit debate, but here's how you could do it with the defaults init manager that Debian / Ubuntu is shipped with.

- Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/geth@.service` and fill it with that:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=geth Ethereum daemon
  Requires=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=forking
  User=%I
  ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth
  Restart=on-failure

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Change `/home/USERNAME/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth` to wherever your geth is :)
- Once you're done with the file, enable the service `sudo systemctl enable geth@USERNAME.service`
- Then your user can start it with `sudo systemctl start geth@USERNAME.service`

Next time you reboot it should start!

For more details see [`systemd.service`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) man page. There are plenty of options that may be interesting.

Comment: Have tried this. Geth is restarted by systemd all the time. I think you meant "Type=Simple" since geth doesn't fork itself

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I use on Ubuntu via `upstart`.  I put the following in the file `/etc/init/geth.conf`

```
description "geth 1.3.5"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

setuid your_nonroot_user

script
  exec bash -c '/usr/bin/geth --rpc --verbosity "2" 2>>/home/geth/logs/geth'
end script
```

This will start at boot and you can control via `sudo start|stop geth`

Answer (score 2):

### 1. You can add startup app like this

1. Find the location of geth executable using `which geth`
2. Execute the following commands in order

Assume `PATH-TO-GETH` is the result of `which geth`

```
sudo cp PATH-TO-GETH /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/geth 
sudo update-rc.d geth defaults
```

### 2. Run after reboot with crontab

`@reboot /path/to/script`

### 3. Start/Stop Script from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 35 90 12
# description: Geth Instance 
#
# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Start the service GETH
start() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Starting GETH: "
        /path/to/geth &
        ### Create the lock file ###
        touch /var/lock/subsys/geth
        success $"geth startup"
        echo
}
# Restart the service geth
stop() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Stopping GETH: "
        killproc geth
        ### Now, delete the lock file ###
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/geth
        echo
}
### main logic ###
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status geth
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

[How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up/910#910)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take for upstart script for Ubuntu 14.04 as a Ansible playbook template and non-root user:

```
description "geth 1.4.12"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

script
  exec sudo -H -i -u {{ ansible_user }} -- bash -c '/usr/bin/geth {{geth_args}} 2>>/home/{{ansible_user}}/logs/geth.log'
end script
```

Installation - `roles/geth/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  apt: name={{item}} update_cache=yes
  with_items:
  - software-properties-common
  become: yes

- name: Install Ethereum repositories
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:ethereum/ethereum'
  become: yes

- name: Install geth
  apt: name={{item}} update_cache=yes
  with_items:
  - ethereum
  become: yes
  notify:
  - Restart geth

- name: Create logs folder
  file:
    path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/logs"
    state: directory

- name: Setup startup script
  template:
    src: geth.conf
    dest: /etc/init/geth.conf
  become: yes
  notify:
  - Restart geth
```

Answer (score 1):

Running as systemd:

Create geth.service file (/etc/systemd/system/geth.service):

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/geth.service
```

Paste the below

```
[Unit]
Description=Geth

[Service]
Type=simple
User={$USER}
Restart=always
RestartSec=12
ExecStart=/bin/geth --syncmode "full" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Replace {$USER} with username above. Use [useradd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) to create a newUser if required.

```
sudo useradd -d /home/newUser -m --uid 10000 newUser
```

Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

service geth status
sudo service geth start
```

Check the status:

```
service geth status
```

Attaching to geth instance:

```
geth attach
```

Stop and disable the service:

```
sudo service geth stop
sudo systemctl disable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I finally did it...

Create Geth Service File: **/etc/init.d/geth**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          geth
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $named $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $named $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the geth daemon
# Description:       Controls the geth server daemon
### END INIT INFO
#
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
start() {   
   PCOUNT=`pgrep -c geth`
   if ((PCOUNT==1)); then
      /usr/bin/geth --testnet --syncmode=light --rpc --verbosity 0 --cache=1024 &
   fi
   echo $"Geth Started"
}
stop() {
   PCOUNT=`pgrep -c geth`
   if ((PCOUNT>1)); then   
      /usr/bin/killall -9 geth &
   fi
   echo "Geth Stopped"
}
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status geth
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
  echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
  exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Set Permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/geth
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/geth
```

Enable Geth Service

```
sudo update-rc.d geth defaults
sudo update-rc.d geth enable
```