# eth syncing of ethereum classic node in background

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I run ethereum classic node on an amazon ec2 instance. It seems to be running

> ./geth --fast
>   ./geth --exec "eth.syncing"  attach

```
{
  currentBlock: 735772,
  highestBlock: 5565504,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 735504
}
```

- Should I always start my node with --fast to enable sync ?
- how can i leave the ethereum classic node to sync fully from a terminal. It seems to stop when I close terminal. I want it to run in the background. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can run geth as a [systemd service](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-run-go-ethereum-as-daemon-process-on-ubuntu) or have it running in the background with screen or tmux

Answer (score 2):

I'm running ETC Classic node on background on Digital Ocean, and it doesn't stop when i close terminal with this command:
`sudo bash -c 'setsid ./geth --data-dir ../../mnt/volume_sfo2_01/.ethereum-classic --cache 2054 --max-peers 250 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' --rpc --rpc-api 'eth,net,web3' &'`

I'm amateur and Ubuntu is still new to me but will try to explain what I can, so please anyone correct me if I say something wrong, will glad to learn.

`sudo` - I use to run `geth` as far as all data files moved to attached storage (will explain that latter)

`sudo bash -c` - Is command that requires `sudo` permission accessing write to attached storage in particular

`sestid` and `&` at the end of command needed to run `geth` on the background and not showing a log of it to STDOUT

`./geth` - Exctial geth start. I have downloaded `geth` from official repo as tar or zip file don't remember and unzipped to the same directory. Still can't figure out how to make it as a global command.

`--data-dir` - The package I choose when launched new droplet on DO was not enough and I added attached storage 200Gb as of Aug 15, 2018, full node takes 155Gb just FY and moved `./.ethereum-classic` folder to storage.

`--cache 2054` - Just increase the size of memory geth uses.

`--max-peers 250` - Hopped to increase sync speed, more peers more speed ?.

-rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' - To access node from anywhere.

`--rpc --rpc-api 'eth,net,web3'` -Enable RPC server.

I still need to figure out how to set up https connection to the node for more secure interaction.

Answering your question try to run
`setsid ./geth &`

Comment: As alternative use `tmux`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run with testnet ,so you can use this command
./geth --testnet --rpc
otherwise by default it can run on mainnet.