# go-ethereum as daemon process / service on Ubuntu with Toml file

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, ubuntu, daemon

[Created Daemon process](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-run-go-ethereum-as-daemon-process-on-ubuntu) from the Link
The parameter in the `config.toml` Configuration file is not working in the System Service and **geth** configuration is working with default configuration.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=geth -config=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/config.toml
```

How can I run it as go-ethereum as daemon process / service on Ubuntu with Toml file?

Comment: Above Configuration Works. There was a Typo error.

Comment: Please post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Run as a systemd service**
Create a file geth.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ethereum go client

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=geth 2>%h/.ethereum/geth.log

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Enable service:**

```
systemctl --user enable geth.service
systemctl --user start geth.service
```

Source.

Alternatively you could use screen:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install screen -y
Then you can make a bash similar to this (~/geth.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting geth"
screen -dmS geth /usr/bin/geth --verbosity 3
```

now let's make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/geth.sh
```

You can now run the bash ~/geth.sh

You attach to the screen with screen -x geth

You detach from the screen by pressing CTRL + a then d