# etherem private network stopped for unknow reasons

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I have setup an ethereum private network using geth.

but it stopped as server got restarted. Here is the command that i am running.

```
geth -datadir . -rpc -rpcport "8545" -port "30303" --networkid 15 -rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" -rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net
```

Now when i try to rerun it, It is not showing any accounts now and also blocknumber is also showing as 0.

Can anyone let me what should i do to run ethereum from the block where it was terminated?

Comment: When i try to call using api it is saying : (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Comment: If it is running on linux launch it as a serviced see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-run-go-ethereum-as-daemon-process-on-ubuntu. Geth needs to close cleanly. To enable more logs add `--verbosity 4` to geth command line.