# How to run command in Background in AWS?

Tags: go-ethereum, aws, cli

I am executing Ethereum node running command in AWS. I have to keep it running always. I am using screen command but it collapse automatically after some hours. There is another way that is tmux bus is there more sustainable way to keep running process in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Ethereum as a background process.

> Put it into the background like any other Linux process: nohup ./geth --identity ... --networkid 100000 &

From go-ethereum issues: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16307

Other suggestions:
[How can I run go-ethereum as daemon process on Ubuntu?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-run-go-ethereum-as-daemon-process-on-ubuntu)